# Python regex works on Regex101, but it does not work in Python 2

Tags: python, regex

I create a regex to match the Chinese and English name of the TV shows.

My regex is located at https://regex101.com/r/rBJHDG. It is working perfectly on the regex. However, this regex does not work in Python 2.

For examples, string `亿万.Billions.S01E01.中英字幕.HDTVrip.1024X576.mp4`.

The regex does not match `亿万` as `name_chs` in expect. Instead, it matches `亿万.Billions` as `name_en`.

```
In [68]: r = '^(?P<name_chs>(?:[\\u3007\\u4e00-\\u9fff\\u3400-\\u4dbf\\uf900-\\ufaff]+)(?=\\.))?(?P<name_en>\\S+).S(?P<season>\\d{2})E(?P<episode>\\d{2})'

In [69]: re.match(r, u'亿万.Billions.S01E01.中英字幕.HDTVrip.1024X576.mp4').grou
    ...: pdict()
Out[69]:
{'episode': u'01',
 'name_chs': None,
 'name_en': u'\u4ebf\u4e07.Billions',
 'season': u'01'}
```

Second question:

How can I remove the `.` in `name_en` which between the Chinese name and English name?

```
# 亿万.Billions.S01E01.中英字幕.HDTVrip.1024X576.mp4
Full match    0-18    `亿万.Billions.S01E01`
Group `name_chs`    0-2    `亿万`
Group `name_en`    2-11    `.Billions`   <---- This DOT!
Group `season`    13-15    `01`
Group `episode`    16-18    `01`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the regex tester includes the `global` and `multiline` flags but your code does not. If you uncheck those two flags in the regex tester you'll find that the tester matches your current results.

You could try `r = '^(?P<name_chs>(?:[\\u3007\\u4e00-\\u9fff\\u3400-\\u4dbf\\uf900-\\ufaff]+)(?=\\.))?(?P<name_en>\\S+).S(?P<season>\\d{2})E(?P<episode>\\d{2})', re.MULTILINE)`

and

```
re.search(r, u'亿万.Billions.S01E01.中英字幕.HDTVrip.1024X576.mp4').grou
    ...: pdict()
```

As for your second question:

I would just make that dot its own capture group by adding `(.)` in front of the English name, like so...

```
^(?P<name_chs>(?:[\u3007\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\uf900-\ufaff]+)(?=\.))?(.)(?P<name_en>\S+).S(?P<season>\d{2})E(?P<episode>\d{2})
```

Now when you print the English name it will only be the word because the dot is in its own capture group.